# Problema com WHERE e BETWEEN entre duas tabelas MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo um select baseado em um filtro que recebo de um formulario, porem cai em um problema que não sei como resolver.

Tenho duas tabelas, a tabela user e a tabela user_aula. Eu preciso contar o total de aulas que o user deu e depois fazer um BETWEEN em um range que vou receber deste filtro, como fazer isso? O erro que eu tenho como retorno é que a coluna 'aulas_dadas' não existe.

```
SELECT user.*, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM user_aula WHERE user_aula_prof = user.user_id AND user_aula_status IN (1, 2, 3)) as aulas_dadas, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM user_aula WHERE user_aula_aluno = user.user_id AND user_aula_status IN (1,2, 3)) as aulas_feitas 
FROM user 
WHERE user_nome_completo LIKE '%%' 
AND user_email LIKE '%%'
AND user_ref LIKE '%%'
AND user_login BETWEEN '0' AND '9999'
AND aulas_dadas BETWEEN '0' AND '9999'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com *subquery* resolve-se isso fácil:

```
SELECT T.* FROM (
SELECT user.*, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM user_aula WHERE user_aula_prof = user.user_id AND user_aula_status IN (1, 2, 3)) as aulas_dadas, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM user_aula WHERE user_aula_aluno = user.user_id AND user_aula_status IN (1,2, 3)) as aulas_feitas 
FROM user 
WHERE user_nome_completo LIKE '%%' 
AND user_email LIKE '%%'
AND user_ref LIKE '%%') T
WHERE T.aulas_feitas BETWEEN 0 AND 9999
AND T.aulas_dadas BETWEEN 0 AND 9999
```

Assim vc cria filtros no resultado da sua query principal.
Eu gosto mais de trabalhar com funções analíticas de um BD, mas confesso que não conheço as do MySQL.

Comment: Muito obrigado!